# JavaScript (Google Script Custom Function) Not Reading Array Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a simple custom function to iterate through a column, and if a cell has a certain value, to check the value of a different column in that same row. If the value in that cell has a certain value, increase a counter. For some reason, I am getting a TypeError when trying to read a specific column.

Here is the error message I am getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 22).

Line 22 being:
`if (data[row][0] === "example") {`

Does anyone have any solutions? Thank you.

```
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow, lastCol);
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  var count = 0;

  data.forEach(function (row) {
    if (data[row][0] === email) {
      if(data[row][1] === meeting){
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  });
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
data.forEach(function (row) {
    if (data[row][0] === "maxcaza@gmail.com") {
      if(data[row][1] === "Leadership"){
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  });
```

try

```
data.forEach(function (row) {
    if (row[0] === "maxcaza@gmail.com") {
      if(row][1] === "Leadership"){
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  });
```

The above assumes that the first column might contain "maxcaza@gmail.com" and the second might contain "Leadership"